# i want my tool stay display on desktop even if i click on browser or other program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

i made a simple Tool with **Tkinter**, and i want this tool to stay display on desktop even if i click on browser or other program ,so i want the tool always stay on front until i click minimize .
thank you .

```
import pyautogui as p
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
top.title("past")

def brk():
    

    #from dofus-map.com
    time.sleep(0.2)
    p.moveTo(238,627)
    p.tripleClick()
    p.hotkey('ctrl','c')
    #from website
    time.sleep(0.1)
    p.moveTo(84,742)
    p.tripleClick()
    p.hotkey('ctrl','v')
    #to game
    time.sleep(0.1)
    p.click(88,801)
    p.tripleClick()




but = Button(text="past",width = 6, height = 3, font = ("blood",15,""), bg = "lightgreen", fg = "black" , command=brk)
but.pack()


top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```py
top.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

This will always keep your window on top of the screen, regardless of what other programs you use.

Comment: it Works thank you so much bro ^^ i appreciate it